# Partial String Formatting in Python Logging Formatters

Tags: python, string, logging, mapping, formatter

I'm looking for a way to perform partial string formatting in Python logging formatters.
When trying to define a formatter the following way:

`formatter = logging.Formatter('[num-%d] %(levelname)s %(message)s' % (num,))`

I will get a TypeError with "format requires a mapping" which is reasonable as the interpreter couldn't find 'levelname' and 'message'.
Of course, I would like both 'levelname' and 'message' to remain un-formatted for the logging framework to handle.

As I see, there are two other ways of addressing the issue:

1. `format = '[num-' + str(num) +  '] %(levelname)s %(message)s' % (num,)`
2. `format = '[num-%(num)d] %(levelname)s %(message)s' % dict(num=num, levelname='%(levelname)s', message='%(message)s')`

However, I find both solutions somewhat ugly, and I believe there must be a better way to format only part of the string - either in Python, or using in the python builtin logging framework.
Any Ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('[num-%d] %%(levelname)s %%(message)s' % (num,))
```

You have to give the `Formatter` method your string with `%(...)s` fields. The `%%` will interpret into `%` and therefore can be used.